# Select result from two non relational tables in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am a new bee in Python Django.

I have two tables named Table1 and Table2 and they have no relations with each other.

```
SELECT [COL-1], [COL-2]
FROM [TABLE-1] , [TABLE-2]
WHERE [TABLE-1].[COLUMN NAME 1] = [TABLE 2].[COLUMN NAME 2]
```

How can I write above query in Django ORM.
I have tried `select_related()` but it is not getting data from both tables.

Any help please

Comment: What's the reason why those tables don't have a relation?

Comment: The Djangoish way would be to have models and use the orm to query the db. You can also use a django management command to inspect already existing databases and let django create models for that. You would also have to edit these automatically created models to your needs, because django cant guess everything right for you.

Comment: Write your django code of this tables please

Comment: please post your model definitions

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a very rare one as they are not related. Django does allow filter to reference fields but only for the same model. But than there is always the option of using raw sql queries in Django. Have a look, it might be all you need

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/sql/